# How Can I Do Text Box(left side)

Tags: android

[image: left side warning box]

Look the left side, how can I do it? It's only text; user can't click it because it's for info.

Comment: Unclear. What do you want to replicate?

Comment: I just want to a box at left side. I write in it a word so users can understand which page open...

Comment: please explain your problem little bit more. Do you want do display page no. on left side in that text box?

Comment: Please Edit your question to include your layout xml

Comment: I want to display page name info on left side text box..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can create layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="That's pnly for text(not clickable)"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Info"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello World"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you want like this @Word To

Comment: Thanks but I don't want it. I wanna an info box from left side. "..." is a text for example "You're in MainActivity"

Comment: How can I write text landscape?

Comment: please check our xml file info textview in landscape

Answer (score 4):

you need to set:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

to what ever you want to align to the left

like i did in my example that looks a bit like yours, although i couldn't clearly understand what you wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="apps.radwin.testprojectone.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Thats Only for text.(notClickable)"
        android:textColor="#f00000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

the result of this would be an image like that:

[image]